# Get EC2 status with IP address

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way I could get the status of the `aws` instance knowing only the `IP Address` of the `Ec2` instance?

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-ec2-2015-10-01.html#describeinstancestatus) suggests knowing the instanceId prior calling the api, but what in case I do not have the instanceId?

Comment: If you don't know the id, then you should have other information, such as the running status, tag name, instance type, ami image id, or others, which can help you to filter the instance. Check the keyword `filter` in the document you pasted

Comment: Asker knows the IP Address, which is enough

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=ip-address,Values=publicIP --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].State.Name'
```

Obviously change *publicIP* to your real public IP Address